# ctype_print() best solution for UTF-8 characters

Tags: php, utf-8, ctype

In PHP, what is the best approach to let `ctype_print()` (or is this not possible?) work with UTF-8? Currently when I use it with some UTF-8 characters it fails, for example:

```
ctype_print("Curaçao");
```

(after the Dutch independent island Curaçao) returns `false`.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: This thread talk about this issue and they offer solutions, [here](https://grokbase.com/t/php/php-i18n/102tkqe6rk/ctype-print-returns-false-for-british-pound-symbol-and-non-ascii-symbols)

Answer (score 1):

There is a PCRE/POSIX regular expression character class that matches any printable characters ([reference](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC10)). When used with the `u` modifier, it will match any UTF-8 printable characters:

> [:print:] This matches the same characters as [:graph:] plus space characters that are not controls, that is, characters with the Zs property.

If you are only interested in glyphs and spaces count as no-no, you would use:

> [:graph:] This matches characters that have glyphs that mark the page when printed. In Unicode property terms, it matches all characters with the L, M, N, P, S, or Cf properties

Then, your regular expression would look like:

```
preg_match('~^[[:print:]]+$~u', $string)
```

And a possible function would look like:

```
function is_utf8_printable($string): bool {
    return (bool) preg_match('~^[[:print:]]+$~u', $string);
}
```

This will tell you whether all characters, from the `^` beginning to the `$` end of the string, match the `:print:` character class. Please [see here](https://3v4l.org/9DOIE) for several test string iterations.

Comment: @Petah any follow-up on this oldie you resurrected? (OP hasn't been around for ages.)

Answer (score 0):

The `ctype_print` functions use ASCII symbols only:

Its a [wrapper](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/ctype/ctype.c#L145) over C [isprint](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isprint) function

Use regex

```php
function ctype_print_utf(string $string): bool
{
    return preg_match('/[[:cntrl:]]/', $string) === 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: https://3v4l.org/L9CW9

Comment: Works as `ctype_print`: https://3v4l.org/N6NRK

Answer (score 0):

You can try use code bellow:

```
function ctype_print_unicode($input) {
    return preg_match("~^[\pL\pN\s\"\~". preg_quote("!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}´") ."]+$~u", $input);
}

print ctype_print_unicode('Curaçao');
```

Ouput:

```
1
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/bGbMl